# HTML Jquery Timer Control Local Network

Tags: html, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I help manage an escape room and what we are looking to do is to create a digital timer using a second computer monitor.  A local web page will be displayed on the in-room monitor that has a countdown timer.

My main question is how can I control that clock from a different internal web page using html and javascipt or whatever you think would be the best solution? Thanks!

```
     <! doctype html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
div.timer {
    height:400px;
    font-size:160px;
    font-family:"Erbos Draco 1st Open NBP";
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px;
  color:white; 
}
.control{width: 400px;margin:auto}
body{background-color:black;}
button{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color:white;
    width:120px
}
button#start {background-color:green}
button#pause {background-color:orange}
button#reset {background-color:red}

 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="animate.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="HackTimer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="timer" class="timer animated fadeIn">
            <span class="hour">01</span><span id="colon">:</span><span class="minute">00</span><span id="colon2">:</span><span class="second">00</span>&nbsp<span id="seconds" style="display:none">seconds</span><span class="timesup" style="display:none">Time is up!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <button id="start" onClick="timer.start(1000)">Start</button> 
            <button id="pause" onClick="timer.stop()">Pause</button> 
            <button id="reset" onClick="timer.reset(65)">Reset to 1 Hour</button> 

        </div>
<script>

function _timer(callback)
{
    var time = 0;     //  The default time of the timer
    var mode = 1;     //    Mode: count up or count down
    var status = 0;    //    Status: timer is running or stoped
    var timer_id;    //    This is used by setInterval function

    // this will start the timer ex. start the timer with 1 second interval timer.start(1000) 
    this.start = function(interval)
    {
        interval = (typeof(interval) !== 'undefined') ? interval : 1000;

        if(status == 0)
        {
            status = 1;
            timer_id = setInterval(function()
            {
                switch(mode)
                {
                    default:
                    if(time)
                    {
                        time--;
                        generateTime();
                        if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(time);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    if(time < 86400)
                    {
                        time++;
                        generateTime();
                        if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(time);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }, interval);
        }
    }

    //  Same as the name, this will stop or pause the timer ex. timer.stop()
    this.stop =  function()
    {
        if(status == 1)
        {
            status = 0;
            clearInterval(timer_id);
        }
    }

    // Reset the timer to zero or reset it to your own custom time ex. reset to zero second timer.reset(0)
    this.reset =  function(sec)

    {
        sec = (typeof(sec) !== 'undefined') ? sec : 0;
        time = sec;
        generateTime(time);

    }

    // Change the mode of the timer, count-up (1) or countdown (0)
    this.mode = function(tmode)
    {
        mode = tmode;
    }

    // This methode return the current value of the timer
    this.getTime = function()
    {
        return time;

    }

    // This methode return the current mode of the timer count-up (1) or countdown (0)
    this.getMode = function()
    {
        return mode;
    }

    // This methode return the status of the timer running (1) or stoped (1)
    this.getStatus
    {
        return status;
    }

    // This methode will render the time variable to hour:minute:second format
    function generateTime()
    {
        //var millisecond = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60;
        var second = time % 60;
        var minute = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60;
        var hour = Math.floor(time / 3600) % 60;

        //millisecond = (millisecond < 10) ? '0'+millisecond : millisecond;
        second = (second < 10) ? '0'+second : second;
        minute = (minute < 10) ? '0'+minute : minute;
        hour = (hour < 10) ? '0'+hour : hour;

        //$('div.timer span.milliseconds').html(millisecond);
        $('div.timer span.second').html(second);
        $('div.timer span.minute').html(minute);
        $('div.timer span.hour').html(hour);

        document.title = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + ' remaining';
    }
}

// example use
var timer;

$(document).ready(function(e) 
{

    timer = new _timer
    (
        function(time)
        {        
        if(time <= 3600)
            { 
              //$('span.hour').hide();
              //$('span#colon').hide();
            }

        if(time >= 60)
            { 
              $('div.timer').css('color','#32CD32');
            }
        if(time < 60)
            { 
              $('span#seconds').hide();
              $('span.milliseconds').show();
              $('div#timer').removeClass('tada');
              $('div#timer').addClass('fast');

              $('div.timer').css('color','yellow');
                $('span.timesup').hide();
                $('span.minute').show();
                $('span#colon2').show();
                $('span.second').show();
                $('span.milliseconds').show();
                $('span.hour').show();
                $('span#colon').show();
                $('div#timer').css('margin','5px');
                $('div#timer').css('font-size','160px');
            }

        if(time == 0)
            {
                timer.stop();
                $('div.timer').css('color','red');
                $('span.timesup').show();
                $('span.minute').hide();
                $('span#colon2').hide();
                $('span.second').hide();
                $('span.milliseconds').hide();
                $('span.hour').hide();
                $('span#colon').hide();
             $('div#timer').css('font-size','100px');
            }
        }
    );
    timer.reset(0);
    timer.mode(0);


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you asking how to control two monitors independently or how to work with javascript? That seems like quite a broad question?

Comment: I need to control the timer on the in-room monitor without showing start/stop/reset buttons.  I've tried loading the timer div with jQuery .load but is static.  Same result with iframe.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your page and highlight what you want to hide. Perhaps it's a straightforward thing than using any jquery. Also include any relevant code.

Comment: You will need a simple client-server structure. How it may be implemented will depend on who controls/displays the in-room monitor and the second monitor. Is it the same computer (then plain old JavaScript should be enough) or are they different computers (some server side scripting may be needed)?

Comment: Ive updated the question to include what I have. This would be used as a second monitor. Just looking to hide the buttons on the second screen.